# Kinect RGB camera not working but IR camera works in python

Tags: python, opencv, kinect

I just trying to open the Kinect v2 RGB camera with `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and it's not showing the video but if I change the video rotation of Kinect in windows settings it will work with IR camera.

How can I use RGB camera?

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while vid.isOpened():
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    if not ret:
       break

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Errors:

1. [ WARN:0@1.522] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (464) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -2147024809
2. [ WARN:0@1.527] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (476) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -2147024809
3. [ WARN:1@1.532] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1752) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147024809
4. [ WARN:1@1.543] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (539) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it's not working"? What's your code? How are you expecting it to work? What happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should test a different [opencv backend](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html), per default it's on `CAP_ANY` (auto detect) and it looks like it's trying to use MSMF in your windows OS.

Google says for Kintect on windows `CAP_OPENNI2` should be working.

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_OPENNI2)
```

Comment: It runs with no error now but still doesn't show the video. I checked the link. should I install a specific  version of openCV for backend configs? @sre

Comment: I don't know, maybe you have to install it from source with some special flags for openni2.

Maybe cv2.getBuildInformation() gives you more informations to the openni backend.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,you can use the

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

instead
it seems is the problem of Windows MSMF api
you can use the Directorshow api instead
I meet this problem before and slove it in this way.I hope that answer will help you.